# What does the colored square after my equipment's name mean?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

In my equipment list some, but not all, items have a colored square after their name, e.g. "Leather Helm S" has a brown square, "Yukumo Sky Kote" has a red square, but "Leather Vest" has no square.

What does the square, and its different colors, mean?

Comment: Pretty sure that indicator means you can recolor that piece of equipment.  It's only available on high rank and above equipment, but I'm not sure how to actually go about changing it's color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

High and G Rank armors can be recoloured, as indicated by the square next to the equipment. The colour indicates what colour it currently is. You can recolour the equipment via your equipment box, by going to `manage appearance > change armor pigment`. Note though, that this doesn't change the entire colour scheme of the armor.